# Is it possible to drive a PMDC motor with an AC VFD?

Tags: ac, vfd

I wish to run a PMDC motor of 2.2KW with AC VFD but am not sure if it can be done. I am not an Electronic/Electrical guy. Any suggestions will help.

Comment: @Jasen PMDC stands for permanent magnet DC, its a brush motor.

Comment: If you put a 6 diode bridge at the output of VFD, than it could possibly run, but it's a pit using VFD for that, there are cheaper solutions.

Comment: You can run it (with a rectifier as Marko says) but you won't get speed control that way so it's pointless. Use a DC motor (PWM) speed control.

Comment: VFD will reduce voltage and frequency in the same ratio, so by using a bridge rectifier to make DC from the AC you will get speed control

Answer (score 1):

VFDs are AC drives which cannot be used for DC motors. Use a DC Drive for DC motors which gives the ability for speed control. Following link will help you to select one. http://www.ebay.com/sch/DC-Drives-/78190/i.html 
But I believe that buying a AC motor of 3hp (2.2kw) will cost you less than a 3hp (2.2kw) DC drive, if you already have a VFD.

Comment: a 3KW PWM drive is only about 15  bucks, http://www.aliexpress.com/item/J34-Free-Shipping-DC-10-50V-60A-Motor-Speed-Control-PWM-HHO-RC-Controller-12V-24V/32443231224.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.1.iPzMXh&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_1,searchweb201602_5_505_506_503_504_10034_10032_10020_502_10001_10002_10017_10010_10005_10006_10011_10003_10021_10004_10022_10009_10008_10018_10019,searchweb201603_2&btsid=7ffd08eb-2847-4595-b763-ae0f81073534  I guess it depends how cheap the induction motor is.

Comment: @jasen the drive is good in price but these Chinese circuits won't last much longer and they can't deliver the power indicated according to my experience with inverters. FETs  of the circuit can't handle the rated power. Besides don't you think the price is somewhat funny?

Comment: it's PWM, The FETs don't "handle" the power, they just switch the current on and off. the FETS themselves should dissipate very little power.

Comment: @jasen ?? guess why they have heatsinks if they are just switching. PWM dissipates heat.

Comment: they have heatsinks because very little of 3KW is still a enough to need a heastink.r.